# How to make an expanding circle with button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make first circle can expanding as big as the second circle in the background with button, do anyone know how ?

Comment: used backgroundcolor or border radius for this and google search , try to some code your self .

Comment: way to vague I'm afraid. What language/platform? There are no tags,nothing in the title. You're not giving anything away here

Comment: @Madivad there are tags in the question, not need to put them in the title. Although, there is very little to go on, that *is* true.

Comment: @Quoid those tags weren't there originally. :)

Comment: @Jonathon i have 2 circle and one button so far. But i don't know how to make the circle expand works with button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one way to do it would be to use java script to add and remove classes which hold the properties of your circle. 
You could create a css class that holds one set of properties that is then called by javascript when a button is clicked.

```css
.circle_b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}

.circle_s {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  background: coral;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.sizePlus{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}


button{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).click(function (e) {
      $el = $(e.target);
     if ($el.hasClass('clickme')) {
          $(".circle_s").toggleClass('sizePlus');

      } else {
          $(".circle_s").removeClass('sizePlus');
      }
  });
  </script>
  <div class="circle_b">
    <button class="circle_s clickme">
    CLICK ME
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: is it a must using script source ? Thanks Before :)

Comment: well I said " one way to do it would be...", that means that is not the only option. You could probably use CSS to do it as well but that is much more work than just some simple lines of js code. for certain animations and User defined interactions, JS seems to do just fine. At the end the decision is all on you.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/19cy0ua6/1/)

Animation is on hover of button

HTML

```
<div class="circle_b">
  <button class="circle_s">
      HOVER ME!
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circle_b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}

.circle_s {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  background: coral;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.circle_s:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```